# How to create themes in vue/webpack using LESS

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, webpack, less

I am using vue with webpack to write Single File Components, using `less-loader` to parse `<style lang="less"></style>` fields in the component files

I'm looking for a nice way to be able to write themes for the site. Ideally I would like to have separate `theme.less` files like so:

```
src
|--themes
|  |-- light.less
|  |-- dark.less
|--components
   |-- app.vue
   |-- nav.vue
```

Where the theme.less file is composed of generic variables:

```less
@bg:      hsl(251, 44%, 95%);
@sub:     hsl(251, 18%, 81%);
@surface: hsl(251, 18%, 81%);
@text:    hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
@link:    ...
```

So that I can write component-level styles in a theme-agnostic way:

```html
<style lang="less">
    #main-content {
        background-color: @bg;
        color: @text;
        border: @primary;
    }
</style>
```

And generate css that wraps my provided styles in themed classes:

```less
.light #main-content {
    background-color: [@bg variable in light.less];
    color: [@text variable in light.less];
    border: [@primary variable in light.less];
}

.dark #main-content {
    background-color: [@bg variable in dark.less];
    color: [@text variable in dark.less];
    border: [@primary variable in dark.less];
}
```

So that I can apply a theme class to the root element like `<body class="dark">` and display the appropriate styles.

What is the best way to do this?

---

---

Currently I have implemented my own solution which uses the `inject` feature provided by `style-resources-loader`:

```js
module.exports = function (source, resources) {
    let newSource = source.trim();

    let themes = resources.map(v => {
        let o = {};
        o.default = v.content.startsWith("/**DEFAULT**/");
        o.name = v.file.split('/').pop().replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
        return o;
    });

    let wrappers = themes.map(v => `
${v.default ? 'body' : '.' + v.name} {
    @import (reference) '../themes/${v.name}.less';
`);

    let compiled = "";
    wrappers.forEach(w => {
        compiled += w + newSource + '\n}\n';
    })

    return compiled
}
```

What this does is for each component's `style` code, it creates multiple theme-class blocks like

```less
.light { 
    @import (reference) '../themes/light.less';
    [injected source code]
}

.dark { 
    @import (reference) '../themes/dark.less';
    [injected source code]
}
```

And inserts the style code after the import, allowing the `@variable` references in my components to be scoped to the theme, and outputting css with all styles wrapped in multiple theme classes (therefore duplicating all the styles I write for every theme I have available)

I am mainly asking if there is a better way to achieve this, possibly through some built-in functionality within webpack, vue, or less that I have overlooked.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same need. I, however, chose another approach using [CSS Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) (aka CSS variables).

Refactor your LESS variables like:

```
@bg:      var(--bg, lime);
@sub:     var(--sub, lime);
@surface: var(--surface, lime);
@text:    var(--text, lime);
@link:    ...
```

Then define your CSS variables per theme:

```
:root {
  --bg:      hsl(251, 44%, 95%);
  --sub:     hsl(251, 18%, 81%);
  --surface: hsl(251, 18%, 81%);
  --text:    hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
  --link:    ...
}
```

That's basically everything you need. It works pretty nicely and even have the added benefit that I can even play with the colors directly in the browser using the dev tools or add them as user settings to allow users defining their own themes.

Comment: So with this solution would you have the CSS variables defined in the dark.less and light.less files then import those into something like a main.less file?

Comment: That would be a straightforward usage yes. You'll have to make your own decisions based on your needs whether to load all themes and toggle them by e.g. toggling a (class) attribute on e.g. body-element or make something more advanced where themes are loaded on demand.